# Cannot retrieve attr_accessor in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project and I have two models:

**1. User**

**2. Merchant**

their relationships are:

**User has_one :merchant**

**Merchant belongs_to :user**

then in my **user.rb**

```
attr_accessor :merchant_name
after_create :create_merchant

def create_merchant
  create_merchant(name: merchant_name)
end
```

In my user's form:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.text_field :merchant_name
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.text_field :password
```

the problem is the user and a merchant has been created but the merchant's name is nil

In my **Account::RegistrationsController**

```
class Account::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    account_users_path
  end


  private

  def registration_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:merchant_name)
  end

end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  Processing by Account::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ht8vHG8I4bz2ylt+mtLC7hilQnK3VnYtcHgSNv8nSeg=", "user"=>{"merchant_name"=>"Zara 123", "email"=>"allen.chun@hotmail.com", 
"password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}

    Unpermitted parameters: merchant_name
```

Comment: Add your controller action, that receive this form request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't override the create_merchant method if I were you, try something like this:

```
after_create -> { create_merchant!(:name => self.merchant_name) }
```

and make sure your merchant_name is permitted in the users controller, something like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:merchant_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: Updated my question, please check the last part.

Comment: or you can post your controller code and let us have a look

Comment: Your solution doesn't taking into account devise gem. I provided a link where there is a proper way to permit params.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it should be

```
attr_accessor :merchant_name
after_create :create_merchant

def create_merchant
  build_merchant(name: merchant_name)
  save
end
```

create_association [hasn't supported in rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/create_association)

Also don't forget [to permit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) `merchant_name`. According to this info:

```
class Account::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    account_users_path
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :merchant_name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting a nil name on saved merchant

Comment: My mistake. You probably should `build_merchant`, and then save model. Maybe this will help.

Comment: I'm still getting a nil name on merchant

Comment: Could you add controller action, where you create user? Or it's standard devise thing?

Comment: And has User model a `merchant_name` property in database? Or you just add this field there to later use for `merchant` creation? I don't think it's a right way.

Comment: Ok, and strong parameters also permit `merchant_name`?

Comment: Updated my question, please check the last part